# mySQL Query Multiple Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by

How would I combine these two queries into 1 and to run efficiently on a large table?

```
SELECT  field1, count(1) as requestCount
FROM table1
WHERE date_complete >= '2012-06-12 00:00:00' 
      AND date_complete <= '2012-07-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY field1

SELECT field2, count(1) as completeCount
FROM table1
WHERE date_complete >= '2012-06-12 00:00:00' 
      AND date_complete <= '2012-07-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY field2
```

Table holds information for a process where multiple users are involved.  For example say the first person creates the request, second person completes the request and the third closes out the request by filing it.

I want to count how many each user requested, completed and filed in a specific time frame

I want these two combined to look like

```
+----------------+--------------+
| field1         | requestCount |
+----------------+--------------+
| PJB            |            1 |
| RFD            |            6 |
| YAS            |            4 |
+----------------+--------------+

+

+---------+---------------+
| field2  | completeCount |
+---------+---------------+
| PJB     |            4  |
| YAS     |            5  |
+---------+---------------+

=

+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| Username       | requestCount | completeCount |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| PJB            |            1 |             4 |
| RFD            |            6 |             0 |
| YAS            |            4 |             5 |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: what is the content of the table and what is your expected result

Comment: This looks like a simple `UNION ALL` between them.

Comment: please show us a resultset of the table you want.

Comment: Do you want both the result in one resultant table?

Comment: @Sashi Kant I jsut want this done in one query

Comment: Why the sums are different? `1+6+4 = 11` while `82+0+41 = 123`

Comment: @ypercube I updated to make more sense, there can never be more completed then requested you are right.

Comment: Still, how can the count be 11 in one and 9 in the other count?

Comment: @ypercube becuase those requests are still pending and not yet completed by a user.  Someone REQUESTS something to be completed and they are waiting for a user to COMPLETE and then to FILE the paperwork.

Comment: If you have 11 rows in that period, the total count should be 11. How is pending distinguished from completed? Are there Nulls in those `field1`and `field2` columns?

Comment: yes they would just be null hence they wouldnt be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  o.USERNAME, a.requestCount , b.completeCount from (SELECT  USERNAME
FROM owner_login_pass )
 as o left join (SELECT field1, count(1) as requestCount
FROM table1
WHERE date_complete between '2012-06-12 00:00:00' and '2012-07-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY field1) as a on o.USERNAME=a.field1
left join (SELECT field2, count(1) as completeCount
FROM table1
WHERE date_complete between '2012-06-12 00:00:00' and '2012-07-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY field2) as b on o.USERNAME=b.field2
```

You would need to ensure that field1 has all of the users that you would need to display data for.  Otherwise, you would need to join to a users table as well.

Comment: this looks like what I want.  field1 might not have all the users in field 2.  How would I join it from the table to ensure I have all the users. Also "as b on a.field1=b.field1" should be "as b on a.field1=b.field2"

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here but I think you need:

```
SELECT
    u .Username
  , t1.requestCount
  , t2.completeCount
FROM
        ( SELECT field1 AS Username
          FROM table1
          UNION
          SELECT field2
          FROM table2
        ) AS u
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT field1
               , COUNT(*) AS requestCount
          FROM table1
          WHERE date_complete >= '2012-06-12' 
            AND date_complete < '2012-07-13' 
          GROUP BY field1
        ) AS t1  
            ON t1.field1 = u.Username
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT field2
               , COUNT(*) AS completeCount
          FROM table1
          WHERE date_complete >= '2012-06-12' 
            AND date_complete < '2012-07-13' 
          GROUP BY field2 
        ) AS t2
            ON t2.field2 = u.Username   
;
```

If you have a `user` table, simply replace the first derived table with `user AS u`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can combine them (other than with `UNION`), but you can improve it slightly by using: `WHERE date_complete BETWEEN '2012-06-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-12 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need :::

```
Select * from 
(
   SELECT  field1, count(1) as requestCount
FROM table1
WHERE date_complete between '2012-06-12 00:00:00' and '2012-07-12 23:59:59'  
GROUP BY field1 ) tab1
left join
(
SELECT fied2, count(1) as completeCount
FROM table1
WHERE date_complete between '2012-06-12 00:00:00' and '2012-07-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY field2) tab2 on (tab1.field1 = tab2.field2)
```

Comment: hmm this doesn't output what I was thinking it should.

Comment: so i asked you for the table content and the result you need

Comment: yeah sorry I updated my question let me know if that does nto help

Comment: @Robert: please show a snapshot of the result you want in the resultant table

Comment: I updated to what I want.  I also have a user's table if that would somehow play into a join to make this possible